# First text box wont resign first responder

Tags: objective-c, ios, textbox, uipickerview

I have three text fields.  They are populated by a UI Picker selection.  First text field `text1` wont resign the picker, other two boxes work fine.  I have checked and triple checked the code.  I really dont understand why it wont resign.

```
 }
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component

{

NSInteger selectedRow = [select selectedRowInComponent:0];
    if([text1 isFirstResponder])
    text1.text = [arrStatus objectAtIndex: selectedRow];

else{
    NSInteger selectedRow = [select2 selectedRowInComponent:0];
    if ([text2 isFirstResponder])
        text2.text = [arrStatus2 objectAtIndex: selectedRow];

else{
    NSInteger selectedRow = [select3 selectedRowInComponent:0];
    if ([text3 isFirstResponder])
        text3.text = [arrStatus3 objectAtIndex: selectedRow];




    }


[text1 resignFirstResponder]; //<<<wont resign first responder
[text2 resignFirstResponder];
[text3 resignFirstResponder];



  }



}
```

UPDATE-I can resign the `text1` using a button, for some reason it wont resign in the `didSelectRow` method

Comment: Are you sure `text1` is not nil at this point in the code?  Are you sure this code is being called when `text1` should be resigning?

Comment: Not sure I understand, if I try and put the `resignFirstReposnder` under the `if` statements I get an "expected expression" error for `else`

Comment: That is probably because you aren't putting `{}`s around the `if`'s code block

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@", [text1 description])` to see what you're actually calling `resignFirstResponder on.

Comment: @ Dustin  `2012-07-31 15:31:40.309 picker[2846:c07] <UITextField: 0x689fa60; frame = (106 124; 97 31); text = '2'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x6859ea0>>`  Never used NS log thanks for the tip, I think its calling text box 2, next questions...How to remedy that

Comment: scratch that, its just telling me the number selected

Comment: are you sure this is exact mirrored method from your code? it seems pure chaos... where are close brackets? O.o

Comment: The close brackets got missed off during copy and paste.  Now edited and yes exact mirror of code - Whats purely chaotic about it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok then can you try one thing.

Assign the textField to a member variable in `textFieldDidbeginEditing`

And in your picker method resign the memberVariable object.

Instead of resigning the keyboard inside the if condition. Can you put it outside.
Please try something like this.

```
{
    {

    NSInteger selectedRow = [select selectedRowInComponent:0];
        if([text1 isFirstResponder])
            text1.text = [arrStatus objectAtIndex: selectedRow];
    else
    {
        NSInteger selectedRow = [select2 selectedRowInComponent:0];
            if ([text2 isFirstResponder])
            text2.text = [arrStatus2 objectAtIndex: selectedRow];
            else
        {
                NSInteger selectedRow = [select3 selectedRowInComponent:0];
                if ([text3 isFirstResponder])
                 text3.text = [arrStatus3 objectAtIndex: selectedRow];
         }
     }

    }
[selectedTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Ok, Any hints on how to do that would be great if you dont mind. I  have no idea what that is. Looked on google and no help.

Comment: add `UITextField *selectedTextField` in your .h file,  Now add the textField delegate method in your .m file `- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` assign `selectedTextField = textField;` But first of all make sure that you have set the Delegate of the textField to self. Now in your picker method, try `[selectedTextField resignFirstResponder];`

Comment: thanks not working, I can reign it from a ui button using IBAction bizzarley?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this, curly braces to the rescue!

```
{
    {
    NSInteger selectedRow = [select selectedRowInComponent:0];
    if([text1 isFirstResponder])
    {
    text1.text = [arrStatus objectAtIndex: selectedRow];
         [text1 resignFirstResponder];
    }
else{
    NSInteger selectedRow = [select2 selectedRowInComponent:0];
    if ([text2 isFirstResponder])
    {
    text2.text = [arrStatus2 objectAtIndex: selectedRow];
         [text2 resignFirstResponder];
    }
else{
    NSInteger selectedRow = [select3 selectedRowInComponent:0];
    if ([text3 isFirstResponder])
    {
    text3.text = [arrStatus3 objectAtIndex: selectedRow];
         [text3 resignFirstResponder];
    }




  }

  }



}
```